# How to pause Audio when the same Audio is playing in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
const gameSounds = {
  backgroundTheme: function(){
    const backgroundTheme = new Audio('./gameSounds/theme.mp3');

    if(backgroundTheme){
      backgroundTheme.pause();
    }
      backgroundTheme.play();
    
  }
```

I have a start button that I have added an event listener of click and when the click happens then the audio will begin playing but at the moment you can click the start button multiple times and the audio will play several times at the same time which is not something I want to happen.

I thought of writing an if statement that would check if the audio is already playing then pause it or restart it but I am not sure what to write inside the if() I tried if(backgroundTheme.play()) but that didn't work... Any ideas ?

Comment: First you need to move your audio instance out of your function or it will indeed create a new instance every time, once you have done that you could look at the paused property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you must create `new Audio` only once and act on it later on.

Have global variable that holds state of your player:

```js
var audioObject;
var isPlaying = false;

const gameSounds = {
  backgroundTheme: function(){
    if (typeof audioObject === 'undefined') {
        audioObject = new Audio('./gameSounds/theme.mp3');
    }

    if(isPlaying){
      backgroundTheme.pause();
    } else {
      backgroundTheme.play();
    }

    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  }
```

Comment: That worked as a charm thanks a lot, Do you also know how to make it loop ?

Comment: @Whyudodis https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+loop+audio+in+js